# Hive2 query runs on hue editor but fails in oozie workflow

Tags: hive, workflow, putty, oozie, beeline

my hive sql query runs perfect in putty and also in hue editor. But when I try to create a workflow in Oozie, it fails with the following error -

`Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.Hive2Main], exit code [2]`

can you help me on this!

Comment: Please provide more info i.e. how do you define Oozie workflow - is it a Hive action, shell action, args, files..

Comment: @mazaneicha I saved the script in .hql file and running it in HiveServer2 Script action.

Comment: Did you copy your .hql file to hdfs, and did you add it to "Files" in Oozie action definition?

Comment: You are correct. I uploaded my .hql file to hdfs and I added to files in oozie action @mazaneicha

Comment: Do you have HiveServer2 URL defined on the properties tab of Hue/oozie action, e.g. jdbc:hive2://<HIVE_SERVER_HOSTNAME>:10000/default ?

Comment: @mazaneicha Yes I did.. I tried to run it through oozie workflow editor in my documents. I'm looking at this error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Comment: Sounds like a different error than that was originally in your question... A quick googling shows this, for example https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/115009269307-Unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-metadata-SessionHiveMetaStoreClient. But technically, you should post a new SO question.

Comment: @mazaneicha ignoring my previous comment, is there something to resolve this below error?

Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.Hive2Main], exit code [2]

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing how your query looks like but it might worth to double check comments in your hql file if you have any.
For instance, this query

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 1,2
) tbl
WHERE
1 = 1; -- some description goes here
ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME TO your_table;
```

will be executed via HUE as 2 different ones, but once it runs via Oozie's Hive2 action you will see that "ALTER TABLE ..." becomes a part of comment of your "SELECT ...".
So potential solution might look like

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 1,2
) tbl
WHERE
1 = 1; -- some description goes here;
ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME TO your_table;
```

or just drop the comment altogether